# Write to console after async loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to do async loop, where I do something and after it ends, I write to the console. It's look like that:

```
const http = require('http');

async function load(link)
{
    try{
        http.get(link, response => console.log(`File: ${link}`));
    }catch(e){
        console.log('error');
    }
}

async function loop(arrayOfLinks)
{
    for(let link of arrayOfLinks)
        load(link);
}

module.exports = (arrayOfLinks) => {
    (async () => {
        await loop(arrayOfLinks);
        console.log('Files: '+arrayOfLinks.length);
    })();
}
```

But, what I have:

> Files: 3
>   File: http://localhost:8000/1.jpg
>   File: http://localhost:8000/2.jpg
>   File: http://localhost:8000/3.jpg

And what I want:

> File: http://localhost:8000/1.jpg
>   File: http://localhost:8000/2.jpg
>   File: http://localhost:8000/3.jpg
>   Files: 3

**Questions:**

1. Why `await` operator doesn't block the next step?
2. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `await http.get(link, response => console.log(\`File: ${link}\`));` and `await load(link);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure `load` function returns Promise. `http.get` by itself is not going to return it so you want to wrap it (or use promise based HTTP library, like `fetch`, etc).

Simple promise wrapper could look like this:

```
async function load(link) {
  try {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      http.get(link, resolve).on('error', reject)
    })
    .then(response => console.log(`File: ${link}`))
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('error', e.message);
  }
}

async function loop(arrayOfLinks) {
  for (let link of arrayOfLinks)
    await load(link);
}
```

You also need to use `await load(link)` in `loop`.

Comment: But if I do `for(let link of arrayOfLinks) await load(link)`, it will no longer be an asynchronous loop, right? Because there is **await**

Comment: It is still async behind the scene, but syntaically it's asynchronous, yes.